# Create new radio button options during runtime

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I am using JavaFX and would like that when a button is clicked, a new radio button is created and displayed within a flowpane. Is this possible? I tried to do this but nothing seems to appear.

**Edit:**
The problem seems to be originating from the insertDemand() method in the Controller class. The radio buttons appear if I remove the first two lines of the method. I have no idea why it does this. But I need when the button is clicked a line to appear on the screen as well as the radio button to appear so removing these two lines is not a feasible solution.

Here is the fxml:

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="/sample/sample.css" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.76-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <!--Insert-->
        <ScrollPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="4">
            <content>
                <FlowPane>
                    <Button fx:id="demandB" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#insertDemand"  text="Demand" />
                </FlowPane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
        <StackPane fx:id="workspaceSP" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
        </StackPane>
        <ScrollPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
            <content>
                <FlowPane fx:id="lineButtonsFP" prefHeight="100.0">
                    <Label text="Select a Curve:" />

                </FlowPane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </children>
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="600.0" minWidth="392.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="200.0" minHeight="22.0" prefHeight="39.0" />
        <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

Here is the Controller class:

```
public class Controller {

    static Parent graphMaker;
    @FXML
    StackPane workspaceSP;
    @FXML
    FlowPane lineButtonsFP;
    static LinkedList<Demand> curvesLL;
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    public void insertDemand() {
        Demand demand = new Demand(workspaceSP,200,200,400,400);
        curvesLL.add(demand);
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("Demand");
        radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
        radioButton.setSelected(true);
        lineButtonsFP.getChildren().add(radioButton);
    }
}
```

Demand is a class I've made. When created, a line is displayed:

```
public class Demand {

        public Demand(Pane pane, double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY){
            pane.getChildren().add(makeLine(startX, startY, endX, endY));
        }

        private Line makeLine(double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY) {
            Line line = new Line(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            return line;
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help :)

**Edit 2:** I found how to make it work. No idea why this fixes the problem but if you move the first two lines of the insertDemand() method to the bottom so that the radio button is made first and then the Deman object is created, then it works.

Comment: I'm no expert here but I'd guess you need to use the Java API to add new radio buttons at runtime.

Comment: Works for me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: A complete fxml+controller class(+ the code used for loading the fxml maybe?) would show us the issue... The only steps I did to make this work is wrap the `Button` and `FlowPane` in a `VBox` and add your code snippet to the controller. BTW: your window/the `FlowPane`'s parent isn't too small to show the additional children of the `FlowPane` by chance?

Comment: Thanks Fabian for showing me that. I've updated the question. The parent seems to be a good enough size.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple example that works.  I didn't bother with FXML, but I don't see why that would be any different.  If you're still having trouble you need to provide an example that doesn't work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            FlowPane lineButtonsFP = new FlowPane();
            root.setCenter(lineButtonsFP);
            ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

            Button add = new Button("add");
            root.setTop(add);
            add.setOnAction((action) ->
            {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("Demand");
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
                radioButton.setSelected(true);
                lineButtonsFP.getChildren().add(radioButton);                
            });
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for taking the time to write that out. I've updated the post to try and find further what's not working. Appreciate everything!